# How to view the available text file in the sdcard in android?

Tags: android

I have an image and text files in the (SDCard) android emulator. Emulator shows the image files in the gallery. How and where can we view the available text file in the android emulator?

Answer (score 0):

there is no standard 'file explorer' on android, but you can install different ones from market or just install the APK to the emulator:
http://lysesoft.com/products/andexplorer/index.html#download